# Java:Handelling socket with multiple connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hi i am using the following code at the server end for multiple clients to connect..

```
public class Tcpfileserver extends Thread
{      
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;    


    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {           
        Tcpfileserver obj=new Tcpfileserver();
        obj.start();        
    }

public void run()
    { 
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
    while(true) 
                    {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  // accept connection

                        TcpThread t = new TcpThread(socket);    // make a thread of it

                        //System.out.println("Remote IP:"+socket.getInetAddress());

                        //System.out.println("Remote Port:"+socket.getPort());

                        t.start();          
                    }}
```

but when multiple clients connect to my server some of them timeout,why is there a delay from my side to accept connection instantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try specifying maximum number of clients as

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000,10);
```

Here it should accept upto 10 connections without having any problem.
Moreover you can check your statistics using `netstat -a` what will show that port 3000 is still listening even after making connection with one client and has assigned either 3001 ( or greater) / 2999 ( or lesser) port to your existing client.

Comment: @bt the problem is not the number of connection!!sometimes the 2nd client also goes timout..if there is only one client connected

Comment: is this the correct method for handelling multiple connections from your point of view?

Comment: yes i think. have you checked output of this command "netstat -a" ? it should be like your 3000 port should always be in listening state with a local port saying TIME_WAIT and established connection should be in ESTABLISHED state .

Comment: mmm there was some other issue!!but this helpd!!thnks

Comment: what other issues ? i am curious to know ( and for future reference too kindly let others know, by making EDIT post on your question ), this would help others ....

Comment: If the code is as shown that is barely possible other than for networking reasons. If you have more code in your accept loop please show it. The accept loop shouldn't do any blocking operations, and that includes I/O on the accepted socket and DNS operations to log where it came from. Maybe your TCPThread constructor does some or all of that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering to use a framework? 
Give this a try: [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org)

Sample code:

```
public abstract class DefaultServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter {
    private SocketAcceptor acceptor;
    private String socketAddress;
    private int socketPort;

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable t)
        throws Exception {
            log.error(Trace.getStackTrace(t));
            session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object msg) throws Exception {
            //code to process received messages
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(IoSession session) throws Exception {
            log.info("Session created by: " + session.getRemoteAddress());
            if (session.getTransportType() == TransportType.SOCKET) {
                ((SocketSessionConfig) session.getConfig())
                .setReceiveBufferSize(2048);
            }
            session.setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10);
    }

    public void bind() {
            log.info("bind " + socketPort);
            ByteBuffer.setUseDirectBuffers(false);
            ByteBuffer.setAllocator(new SimpleByteBufferAllocator());

            acceptor = new SocketAcceptor();

            ProtocolCodecFilter codec = new ProtocolCodecFilter(
            new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            SocketAcceptorConfig cfg = new SocketAcceptorConfig();
            cfg.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", codec);

            try {
                    acceptor.bind(socketAddress, this, cfg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(Trace.getStackTrace(e));
            }
    }

    public void unbind() {
            log.info("unbind " + socketPort);
            acceptor.unbind(new InetSocketAddress(socketPort));
    }
}
```